# Create extra columns for items with the same id in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have the following data that has been sorted:

```
Id    Items
1      a,b
1       c
2       c
3      a,c
3       d
3       e
```

I would like to reformat into the following format:

```
Id    Items1    Items2     Items3
1      a,b        c
2       c          
3      a,c        d          e
```

Can I use `reshape` to do this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Id~paste0("Items", rowid(Id)), value.var = "Items", fill = "")
#   Id Items1 Items2 Items3
#1:  1    a,b      c       
#2:  2      c              
#3:  3    a,c      d      e
```

Comment: For some reason, my R has problem with the the command "rowid". May I know if there are alternative command I can use to replace that? Thanks

Comment: @tatami It is in the newer versions of `data.table`.  i.e. `1.10.0`  Can you update your data.table version.